# Can i use html for designe the component(ex. button ,combobox) in codenameone without help of gui builder

Tags: codenameone

## I am trying to develop an app without the help of GUI builder using codenameone.

- I am done with the functionality but design is not upto the mark.

  ---

  ```
    my question is how can we increase the look and feel of the    application?
  ```

Answer (score 0):

No. That would inhibit the performance of your application considerably.

You can style the application to look almost any way you want using the designer tools styling capabilities which are unrelated to the GUI builder see:

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-simple-theme.html

E.g. you can do stuff like this:
http://codenameone.com/gallery.html

http://codenameone.com/demos.html